# How to programmatically clear a material design autocomplete in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, material-design

I have a material design autocomplete working correctly. Now I need to be able to clear the selected element when a button is clicked. I see that the element's delete button that appears on the right has an `$mdAutocomplete.clear()` call which is exactly what I need but I don't know how to launch that.

How can I capture the element and call the clear() method?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set the model which is binded to the search text with empty string:

```
self.clear = function() {
  self.searchText = '';
}
```

See this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLeGON)

Comment: Is there any way to do this without opening suggestions and blocking user from clicking again to show them?

Answer (score 0):

```
self.clear = function() {
  self.searchText = '';
}
```

eladcon answer works, but I would set md-min-length="1" to avoid let search box open.